# JavaFX + Scene Builder how switch scene

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm working with JavaFx and Scenebuilder and want create a local app for myself called "Taskplanner" in eclipse.

I created a new Stage and set it with a Scene (see Main.java). But not sure how to set a new Scene in the **old** stage (see Controller.java). Didnt also not find out if it is possible pass the signInButtonClicked()-Methode the "Stage primaryStage" over Scene Builder

Can anybody help ?

**Controller.java:**

```
@FXML
Button btnSignIn;

@FXML
public void signInButtonClicked() throws Exception
{
//Here I want call the new Scene(SignInGUI.fxml) in my old Stage
   FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../view/SignInGUI.fxml"));
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
      {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/LoginGUI.fxml"));

            primaryStage.setTitle("Taskplanner");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,500,500));
            primaryStage.show();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            launch(args);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a reference to the `Scene` and `Window` from your button reference. From there, it's up to you to decide how to you want to show the new view.

Here's how you get those references:

```
Scene scene = btnSignIn.getScene();
Window window = scene.getWindow();
Stage stage = (Stage) window;
```

You can change the view by changing the root of your Scene:

```
FXMLLoader loader = ... // create and load() view
btnSignIn.getScene().setRoot(loader.getRoot());
```

Or you can change the entire Scene:

```
FXMLLoader loader = ... // create and load() view
Stage stage = (Stage) btnSignIn.getScene().getWindow();
Scene scene = new Scene(loader.getRoot());
stage.setScene(scene);
```