# New windows open in JavaFX / fxml, but i dont want it to open a new scene

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

When i run my code i open a window with 3 buttons to press, what i want is when i press one of the buttons that opens a new window would just "overtake" the previous window instead of opening a new one, causing me to have 2 open windows instead of 1.
Below is my GUIController:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GUIController {



       public void patientVindue(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
           FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/patientGUI.fxml"));
           GridPane gridPane = loader.load();
           Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.show();
       }

       public void lægeVindue(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
           FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/lægeGUI.fxml"));
           GridPane gridPane = loader.load();
           Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.show();
       }

       public void sundhedsprofessionelVindue(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
           FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sundhedsprofessionelGUI.fxml"));
           GridPane gridPane = loader.load();
           Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.show();
       }

       public tilbageVindue(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
           FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gui.fxml"));
           GridPane gridPane = loader.load();
           Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.show();
       }
    }
```

-- Adding some more information. This is the other class that i use:

```
public class GUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/gui.fxml"));
        GridPane gridPane = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


    }
}
```

Comment: `Stage stage = new Stage(); ... stage.show()` is where the new windows are coming from. Since you want to update the content of the already existing `Stage` you'll need to have a reference to it.

Comment: That makes sense, as you can probably tell i'm pretty new to programming. How would i go about that, the first window is created from another class :)

Comment: If this is indeed about replacing the content of the existing window, this seems to be a duplicate of the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863425/javafx-scene-builder-how-switch-scene (Iirc there was a similar question with different options, like e.g. using `Event.source` to get the object the event handler was registered to, but I cannot find it right now).

Answer (score 0):

you must be making new stage for that window, i would suggest you to make stage static then pass that scene into that stage

Comment: If i make it static, my program (IntelliJ) think it is an error and suggets to remove static. I am most likely doing it wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Create one global Stage and just set the new scenes to that one stage. You are always creating a new Stage and then setting the new scene to that new stage, which is why you are always getting new windows.

MainApp that starts the login page:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Access The Unicorn World");
        showLogin(this.primaryStage);
    }

    public static void showLogin(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/Login.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new LoginController(primaryStage));
            Parent loginLayout = loader.load();

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loginLayout));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Then for the login page I have a Controller that I set above and passed the stage. In the login page I can then do the following when someone hasn't got a account and I want to open the register window:

```
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public LoginController(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    @FXML
    void onRegisterAction(ActionEvent event) {
        showRegister(this.primaryStage);
    }

    public static void showRegister(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/Register.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new RegisterController(primaryStage));
            Parent registerLayout = loader.load();

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(registerLayout));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried using your method, but i can't seem to understand it or make it work for me :/ I've tried creating a new Project and just copying the code into it. But i can't make it work.